# Trying to get property of non-object, from an object

Tags: php, laravel, object, vue.js

I am serializing a form that contains one `select` input with an object as its `value` to be sent to the back-end via Ajax:

```
<select name="language" class="form-control">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Choose a Language</option>
    <option value="{ locale: 'AF', name: 'Afrikaans' }">Afrikaans</option>
    ...
</select>
```

The data is then sent via Ajax, using VueJS:

```
$.post("/ajax/admin/languages", $("#addLanguageForm").serialize()).done((data) => {
    if (data.success) {
        toastr.success("A new language has been added");
    } else {
        toastr.error("An error occurred");
    }
})
```

Then, the method called by the route is triggered, and here I am checking the data by logging it:

```
public function store(Request $r)
{
    $x = $r->input('language');

    Log::info($x);
}
```

Will display the following:

> [2018-01-29 05:52:18] local.INFO: { locale: 'AF', name: 'Afrikaans' }

I then tried to access these keys to store their values by `$x->locale` and `$x->name`, which causes the error, even being an object.

What could I be missing?

Comment: where are you accessing this?? where is your controller code?? may be you could add your ajax call also, that may help others to understand your problem better

Comment: Added the call.

Comment: `json_decode` will not work , because this is not a JSON data format . You need to pass value in JSON format first, then you can use `json_decode` to get values

Comment: But isn't it already a JSON? It seems by the logged value.

Comment: `{
 "locale": "AF",
 "name": "Afrikaans"
}`   this is proper JSON format, that  you are looking for

Comment: @JigarShah, I updated the code, the error persists.

Comment: please post updated code and var_dump

Comment: Tried `json_decode($x):` anywhere before trying to access the values? You need to show us _all_ the relevant code, not just some snippets here and there.

Comment: I hadn't used `json_decode` after modifying the JSON format as @JigarShah suggested. It is now working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help and ideas, I come up with a solution. First, I modified the JSON format as @JigarShah suggested, and then, from within the Controller, following code:

```
public function store(Request $r)
{
    $x = $r->input('language');
    $d = json_decode($x);

    print_r($d->name);
}
```

All ok.